# exec.Command with variable arguments

Tags: variables, go, exec

I'm trying to pass an argument to an exec.Command. *Part* of that argument is a variable.

```
a := fileName
exec.Command("command", "/path/to/"a).Output()
```

I'm not sure of how to approach this, I'm thinking I need to fully form the argument before I even pass it, but I'm also struggling with that option. I'm not sure how to do something like:

```
a := fileName
arg := "/path/to/"a
exec.Command("command", arg).Output()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go strings are concatenated with `+`,

```
exec.Command("command", "/path/to/" + a)
```

You could also using a formatting function

```
exec.Command("command", fmt.Sprintf("/path/to/%s", a))
```

But in this case it's probably more appropriate to use [`filepath.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join)

```
dir := "/path/to/"
exec.Command("command", filepath.Join(dir, a))
```

Comment: Jim,

Thanks for the thorough list of options. I agree, filepath.Join seems to be the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this approach:

```
a := fileName
cmdArgs := []string{"/path/to/" + a, "morearg"}
out, err := exec.Command("command", cmdArgs...).Output()
```